# How to get selected image name in message box?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am retrieving images from database from particular table. It's showing all images from that table.

Now I need to get that selected image name, it's displaying the name using binding and ToolTip, but I need to get when I click the image, selected image  name should be view in message box.

This is my code:

imageView.cs-page.

```
var query1 = DB_Linq.tbl_ItemMaster.Select(cust => new { cust.Item_Code, cust.Item_Image,cust.ImagePath, cust.ItemName_EN }).ToList();


                var QBM1 = (from po in DB_Linq.tbl_ItemMaster
                             where po.ActiveFlag == true
                             select new ImageEntity
                            {
                                ImagePath = po.ImagePath,
                                ItemName_EN = po.ItemName_EN       

                            }
                           );

                return QBM1.ToList<ImageEntity>();
```

ImageEntity.cs

```
class ImageEntity
    {
        public String ImagePath
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public String ItemName_EN
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

Invoice.Xaml.cs-page

```
private void BindImages()
        {
            try
            {
                // Store Data in List Object
                List<ImageEntity> ListImageObj = ImageView.GetAllImagesData();

                // Check List Object Count
                if (ListImageObj.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Bind Data in List Box Control.
                    LsImageGallery.DataContext = ListImageObj;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Xaml code is:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ListBox_HorizontalItems">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>


        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryDataTemplate" x:Name="ImageGalleryDataTemplate"  >
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderBrush="ForestGreen" BorderThickness="3"  Width="120" Height="120" Padding="10" Margin="15" CornerRadius="10">

                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

                        <Image.ToolTip>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>

                            </Grid>
                        </Image.ToolTip>                    

                    </Image>                 

                </Border>
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName_EN}" ToolTip="{Binding ItemName_EN}" />               
                    </Grid>                   
                </Border>
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="DarkGreen" >
                    <Button   Click="ButtonClicked" ToolTip="{Binding ItemName_EN}" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate">

            <!--Display Images on UniformGrid Panel-->
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>



 <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="LsImageGallery"   ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ImageGalleryDataTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate}">
            <ListBox.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1E2A2F" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </ListBox.Background>

        </ListBox>


</Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could have a boolean IsSelected property on ImageEntity that is updated by a clicked event in a trigger in the xaml. And you could have DataTrigger in the xaml such shows items when their IsSelected is set to true and hides them otherwise.

```
<Page.Resources xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Project.Converters">
        <conv:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ListBox_HorizontalItems">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>


        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryDataTemplate" x:Name="ImageGalleryDataTemplate"  >

            <Grid>
                <Border BorderBrush="ForestGreen" BorderThickness="3"  Width="120" Height="120" Padding="10" Margin="15" CornerRadius="10">
                    <!--Note: You'll Need Antother Event Somewhere In Here To Switch IsSelected Back To False To Hide It Again.-->
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseDown="MouseDownEventHandler">

                        <Image.ToolTip>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100"></Image>

                            </Grid>
                        </Image.ToolTip>

                    </Image>

                </Border>
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <!--I Added Code Here To Only Show The TextBlock Whenever The IsSelected Property On Your ImageEntity Class Is True-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName_EN}" ToolTip="{Binding ItemName_EN}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="DarkGreen" >
                    <Button   Click="ButtonClicked" ToolTip="{Binding ItemName_EN}" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate">

            <!--Display Images on UniformGrid Panel-->
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>


Class ImageEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isSelected = false;

        public String ImagePath
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public String ItemName_EN
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get {return isSelected};
            set 
            {
                isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        ///You Need All Of These To Notify The View That The IsSelected Has Changed So That It Will Update
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void NotifiyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

    }

    ///You Need This To Convert The IsSelected Property Above To A Visibility Enum. This Is Used In Your XAML
    namespace Project.Converters
    {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Update summary.
    /// </summary>
    public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString().ToLower() == "false")
                return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            else
                return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    }


class InVoice
{
    private void BindImages()
    {
        try
        {
            // Store Data in List Object
            List<ImageEntity> ListImageObj = ImageView.GetAllImagesData();

            // Check List Object Count
            if (ListImageObj.Count > 0)
            {
                // Bind Data in List Box Control.
                LsImageGallery.DataContext = ListImageObj;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    void MouseDownEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here You'll Probably Need To Cast sender To A FrameworkElement Or Something In Order To Get The Instance Of The ImageEntity That Was Clicked
        //After You Do This, You Can Set The IsSelected Property For The Item To True, And The ItemName_EN Should Automatically Show.
    }


}
```

Comment: Hold on and i'll cook somethin up for ya.

Comment: This should get you pretty darn close to what you want.